# implementing facets with sphinx search

Tags: php, sphinx, facet

I have 5 tables (1-product,2-companies,3-countries,4-properties,5-licence) .There are 2860 products. I have facets with multiple selection.

For example, users select a country, two companies and a property. At this point, we apply the 3 filters to all facets. 
I don't know how to write my query in `sphinx.conf`.

Can I use `LEFT JOIN` in my query?

Should I use `MVA (multi-valued attributes)`?how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe 'sql_query' is just a database query. So pretty much anything the database engine you are using is capable of running. So if using mysql for example, then can use LEFT JOIN.

Yes, can can possible use MVA 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#mva

Would suggest reading the documentation, and comeing back with more specific questions rather than just 'how?' That is too open-ended to be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interactive course on "implementing facets with Sphinx search" / Manticore - https://play.manticoresearch.com/faceting/
I think it's quite relevant to the subject of this question hence may be useful for those who are interested on the matter.